Tab View Horizontal Title Alignment Shifting
I have a tab view app with several child views. My tab view titles should always be aligned leading.
Recently, I noticed when returning from a child view to the parent tab view, the tab view title horizontal alignment changes from leading to centered. I tried all the usual stuff like padding, HStack spacers, frame(maxWidth: .infinity), and VStack alignment. But none of these seem to have any impact on tab view title alignment.
So I am wondering if I'm missing something or if this is a bug.
Thanks for looking.
Try out the complete demo below.
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            TabView {
                Tab("Tab A", systemImage: "a.square") {
                    NavigationStack {
                        TabA()
                    }
                }
                
                Tab("Tab D", systemImage: "b.square") {
                    NavigationStack {
                        TabB()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .tint(.blue)
        .symbolRenderingMode(.hierarchical)
        .symbolVariant(.fill)
    }
}

struct TabA: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack (alignment: .leading) {
            
            Text("Tab A")
                .padding(.leading, 20)
                .padding(.top, 50)
                .padding(.bottom, 20)
            
            List {
                NavigationLink("Nav View A", destination: NavAView())
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
        }
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .toolbar(content: {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {  <- problem here

                    Text("Title A")
                        .font(.title)
                        .bold()
                        .kerning(1.5)
                        .padding(.leading, 10)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        
            }
        }
        )}
}

struct TabB: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack (alignment: .leading) {
            
            Text("Tab B")
                .padding(.leading, 20)
                .padding(.top, 50)
                .padding(.bottom, 20)
            
            List {
                NavigationLink("Nav View B", destination: NavBView())
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
        }
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .toolbar(content: {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {  <- problem here

                    Text("Title B")
                        .font(.title)
                        .bold()
                        .kerning(1.5)
                        .padding(.leading, 10)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        
            }
        }
        )}
}

struct NavAView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Text("Nav A View")
        }
        .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
        .navigationTitle("Nav A View")
    }
}

struct NavBView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Text("Nav B View")
        }
        .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
        .navigationTitle("Nav B View")
    }
}




Can you show a screenshot of the UI your current code produces vs the desired result?

have you tried using ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading), seems to work for me.

@Sweeper: I added a before and after screenshot
